# "pacman" command, what is it about?

Tags: command-line, inkscape

I having problems with Inkscape. I have found [a thread in a forum talking about these problems](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/inkscape-bug-screencaps-attached/7505/15).

The doubt: in that thread they are talking about a command called "pacman". Does that command exist in Ubuntu distros? I have typed "sudo apt install pacman", but Pacman game is intalled...So what is exactly that "pacman" command?

Comment: No, `pacman` is for Arch-based distros.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Linux

Comment: The Pacman game is one thing, the linux command `pacman` is a tool corresponding to Ubuntu's and Debian's `apt`.